# How can I load the current web.config/app.config as XML

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, app-config, configuration-files

I am trying to load a custom section using the standard XmlSerializer from the current app/webapp's config file.

The below solution doesn't work for web apps:

```
var configFilePath =
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
    .FilePath;

if (configFilePath == null || !File.Exists(configFilePath))
    return null;

var xdoc = XDocument.Load(configFilePath);

var section =
    xdoc.Root?.Element("ParentSection")?.Element("MySection");

if (section == null)
    return null;

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyConfigType));

MyConfigType config;

using (var reader = new StringReader(section.ToString()))
{
    config = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as MyConfigType;
}
```

How can this be done easily without check if the current app is a web app or not?

(Without using `System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config file path can be resolved like so:

```
var configFilePath =
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
```

*Answer based on [Sean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26095/sean)'s deleted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27038942/38368 to a different question*

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using Reflection (*untested*):

```
// Initialize ConfigurationManager
var dummy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

object configSystem = typeof(ConfigurationManager).GetField("s_configSystem", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null);
object configHost = configSystem.GetType().GetField("_configHost", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(configSystem);
object configPaths = configHost.GetType().GetProperty("ConfigPaths", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(configHost);
string path = (string)configPaths.GetType().GetProperty("ApplicationConfigUri", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(configPaths);
```